# Adding of external jar file into classpath for jBoss 7

Tags: jar, classpath, external, jboss7.x

I would like to include external jar files into classpath for all configurations of jBoss7.
Is there any way to do this without moving my files somewhere into jboss lib directories? Or better - is there any way to include all jar files in some external directory?

Comment: Why don't you package them with your application?

Comment: bacause they are used not only by EJB on jBoss, but also by some web apps on tomcats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a directory called `modules` where you can put your jars. But to know how to do that you should read [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Extending%20JBoss%20AS%207.html) guide. You may also create a global module that is accessible to all deployments. Look at [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class%20Loading%20in%20AS7) doc.

Answer (score 3):

No answer actually outlines exactly what to do here so here goes.

In your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file, which should be in `webapp/WEB-INF` you need to add the module reference :

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javaee.api">
                <imports>
                    <exclude path="org/apache/xml/security/**" />
                </imports>
            </module>
            <module name="com.sun.xml.bind" slot="main" />
            <module name="com.mycompany.mypackage" slot="1_0" />
            <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc14" slot="main" />    
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

then copy the jar file this dir :

```
C:\[JBoss-Home]\modules\com\mycompany\mypackage\1_0
```

Comment: So what if you need to add a jar that's intended for the server itself and where there is no webapp/WEB-INF, since there is no app?

Comment: @ArjanTijms for the server itself ? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: JACC and JASPIC both require the jars containing an authorization- respectively authentication module to placed at the "server's classpath". Especially for JACC, the server is supposed to reference your classes very early on, before any application archive is deployed. In earlier servers you put your jar in some server/lib and/or used "-cp [location to your jar].