# ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I have developed one application using struts2 and hibernate, which is integrated with Life-ray portal. When ever I am trying to run that application using j-boss5 server then am getting following error.

```
ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"
ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I am not able to load `HibernateSessionFactory` class.

Please let me know the solution for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding your problem.? Are you using an IDE for running your app or the console.? What do you mean by "I am not able to load HibernateSessionFactory class."? Be more specific.! The solution depends on how good you describe your problem.! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Slf4J requires one and only one of - slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar

Depending on your requirements you'll need to download one of the jars and add in classpath.

Comment: I am using only one of those jars, then also getting same error.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/

Use this link to sysout the classpath and check if the jar is actually present in class path. Remember to use sysout and not log

Comment: I added the code which u have provided by link. then i got following paths....                                                     [STDOUT] /C:/Program%20Files/MyEclipse%206.6/lib/tools.jar
[STDOUT] /E:/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/jboss-5.1.0/bin/run.jar         i didn't get what it means exactly. Please explain which path i have to get. I got the same error.

Comment: Basically in java all the jar files which are used by the JVM need to be added to the classpath while starting the application. 
In case of JBoss all the jar files need to be either in the jboss/lib folder, which is not a recommended option.

See below on how to do it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361175/adding-of-external-jar-file-into-classpath-for-jboss-7